# Diels Alder reaction with maleic anhydride. Reactivity of different dienes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I don't understand question 6, although I took notes and the professor mentioned an explanation in class.

Can someone please help using easier terms?

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to change the title of your question. Please note that the reaction is named after *Otto Diels* and *Kurt Alder*. There's no _'s_ in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The compound can rotate into a trans configuration that is not suitable for Diels Alder

b) The compound is locked into a cis configuration that is favorable. Furthermore, a carbon group is slightly electron donating

c) The compound has an electron withdrawing group.

d) <s>What compound is that?</s> It's compounds labelled b) and c)

Comment: Normal demand Diels Alder is enhanced by an electron withdrawing group in the dienophile and an electron donating group in the diene. Look at reaction mechanism tab (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diels%E2%80%93Alder_reaction)

I am not sure as to why that is. I have forgotten.

Comment: Does c) react slower than a) ?